# How to show the result of the conditional operation in this case?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to programming and I'm learning to tinker with Android Studio.

Context:
On the screen, the user enters four values and pressing the button, the sum of the values is performed and the result appears on the screen. But now, I need to also show the result of "sorting", in this case, it is represented by "dpaResult".

Problem:
I need help to know how to show the "dpaResult" result of the conditional operation below. Here's the snippet of code I've done: (I've left some comments inside the code)

```
buttonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int valorS = Integer.valueOf(editValorS.getText().toString());
        int valorT = Integer.valueOf(editValorT.getText().toString());
        int valorU = Integer.valueOf(editValorU.getText().toString());
        int valorV = Integer.valueOf(editValorV.getText().toString());

        //Sums DPA array fields
        int dpa = (valorS + valorT + valorU + valorV);

        //Sorts the DPA Matrix
        if (dpa<=10){
            String dpaResult = "Baixo";
            Log.i("DPA ", dpaResult);
        }else if (dpa>10 && dpa<16){
            String dpaResult = "Médio";
            Log.i("DPA ", dpaResult);
        }else if (dpa>=16){
            String dpaResult = "Alto";
            Log.i("DPA ", dpaResult);
        }

        textResultado.setText(String.valueOf("O resultado é: " + dpa));//Here only shows the sum value, I need the value "dpaResult" too !!
    }
});
```

Note: If you need to, I can put the code in full, including xml.

I thank you for your help

Comment: mekae dpaResult a global variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `dpaResult` and `Log.i(..)` outside the conditional if statements and aggregate to the `textResultado` text value also the dpaResult String, like this:

```
String dpaResult;
//Sorts the DPA Matrix
if (dpa<=10){
    dpaResult = "Baixo";
}else if (dpa>10 && dpa<16){
    dpaResult = "Médio";
}else {
    dpaResult = "Alto";
}

textResultado.setText(String.valueOf("O resultado é: " + dpa + "; Result: " + dpaResult));
```

Comment: You came up with the `else` case *after* I wrote it in my answer and you forgot to remove the initial assignment of  `""` which is only needed if you do not have a pure `else` case (which was the case before the edit)

Answer (score 0):

Make the dpaResult Variable global and use it to set the result. After that use the variable to set the string in the TextView.

```
buttonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int valorS = Integer.valueOf(editValorS.getText().toString());
            int valorT = Integer.valueOf(editValorT.getText().toString());
            int valorU = Integer.valueOf(editValorU.getText().toString());
            int valorV = Integer.valueOf(editValorV.getText().toString());

            //Sums DPA array fields
            int dpa = (valorS + valorT + valorU + valorV);

            String dpaResult = "";
            //Sorts the DPA Matrix
            if (dpa<=10){
                dpaResult = "Baixo";
            }else if (dpa>10 && dpa<16){
                dpaResult = "Médio";
            }else if (dpa>=16){
                dpaResult = "Alto";
            }
            Log.i("DPA ", dpaResult);

            textResultado.setText(String.valueOf("O resultado é: " + dpa + " Result " + dpaResult ));
        }

   });
```

Comment: `Log.i(..)` can be put outside. `textResultado` needs to display also `dpa` as for the comment in the question code, not only `dpaResult`. To be sure `dpaResult` bettter to be declared empty than null.

Comment: @denis_lor yes you are right. That can be done. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should put logic outside of click listener so it can be tested independently.
So create a function in presenter or view model or outside listener and call it from inside listener.

```
 String getDpaResult(int dpa) {
        String dpaResult;
        // Sorts the DPA Matrix
        if (dpa <= 10) {
            dpaResult = "Baixo";
        } else if (dpa > 10 && dpa < 16) {
            dpaResult = "Médio";
        } else { // dpa >= 16
            dpaResult = "Alto";
        }
        return dpaResult;
    }

 Inside Listener

 textResultado.setText(String.valueOf("O resultado é: " + getDpaResult(dpa));//Here only shows the sum value, I need the value "dpaResult" too !!
```